# update perl dancer framework resulting in error message

Tags: perl, frameworks, cpan, dancer

Following this tutorial "https://perlmaven.com/getting-started-with-perl-dancer"
On Windows command line, I run the command "cpanm --verbose Dancer" and that resulted in error "Failed to download http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/B/BI/BIGPRESH/Dancer-1.3202.tar.gz"

Comment: Is there any other output in the error message? If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score -1):

Playing with it I found the old dancer version is no longer work/available. So I ran

> "cpanm --verbose Dancer2"

and that works! with version 2 of dancer.

Comment: This is not true: Dancer is still available, I just installed it on my machine. Something else went wrong with your install. You really should be using Dancer2 anyway, but this doesn't answer the original question.